# Error unlocking LUKS USB Device: Operation not supported

Tags: debian, luks, cryptsetup

I am using a Debian 11 system with cinnamon and trying to unlock a LUKS encrypted USB device with an ext4 filesystem, which I successfully created and can use when I manually use root and unlock it using cryptsetup.

Using nemo, the file browser, it throws an error instantly whether the password is correct or incorrect: `Error unlocking /dev/sdb1: Failed to activate device: Operation not supported`

I learned that nemo uses `gio` to perform these operations, and trying it on the command line I get the same error.

I tried to use `udiskctl unlock -b /dev/sdb1` and got a similar error:

`Error unlocking /dev/sdb1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error unlocking /dev/sdb1: Failed to activate device: Operation not supported`

Why is it showing operation not supported? On previous systems I have been able to use encrypted luks drives in `nemo` with no problem. How can I tell which operation isn't supported? I have found other posts which have errors saying `operation not permitted` which indicates a wrong password, but nothing regarding `operation not supported`

Comment: The *Operation not supported* error comes from libcryptsetup which UDisks uses for unlocking LUKS devices so if you are able to manually open the device using `cryptsetup luksOpen ...` this most likely means there is a bug in UDisks and it feeds libcryptsetup wrong information when trying to open the device. Check journal for additional errors from `udisksd` after running `udisksctl`, there might be some more information available.

Comment: Unable to find any messages from udisksd in the logs relating to this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Since I love to make my life harder, I have previously setup SELinux on this machine. Initially I thought this could be an SELinux related issue, but because there were no associated AVC denials when searching my logs, I figured it wasn't the issue (due to nothing being denied). Today, I figured maybe I would try booting in permissive mode, and then trying the same thing. The operation succeeded.

After checking the logs for denials in permissive mode, I saw a flood of denied actions for udisksd, so I allowed all those and rebooted in enforcing mode, which seems to have solved the issue. Previously I had tried manually running `setenforce 0` to set SELinux to permissive mode after I had already logged in, but this seems to have had no effect. Only booting completely in permissive mode allowed the problem to be solved.

I will also note that running `semodule -DB` which puts SELinux into verbose mode (shows more denial messages which may be hidden) also did not reveal any additional denials, which is another reason why I did not suspect it to be an SELinux issue.